# Adding a row to a Google Spreadsheet using Javascript

Tags: javascript, html, google-sheets, rows

I am trying to add a new row at the end of the table using three textboxes in HTML. So I'm assuming the best way to do it is by Javascript. I am new to Google Docs programming so I am going with what I find on Google even though there is not a lot of information out there.

So I have this table:

https://docs.google.com/spreadsheet/pub?key=0ApLU-4iFz9JYdGkzVlB2YWVDYXcweEYwcTFrRmJUYWc&output=html

I want to add values to the end of the table using txtfield1, txtfield2, and txtfield3 from an HTML.

So `txtfield1.value = "K", txtfield2.value = "11", txtfield3.value = "24-Sep-2012"` but I know how to get that. I just need to understand how a row, or each independent cell is modified in the Google Spreadsheet by using Javascript.

Is this complicated to achieve? I tried looking up tutorials to do this but I couldn't find anything so I'm not sure it's possible to do this.

Comment: You can do this with google apps script, but you will need to write code. Is that an option for you?

Comment: @eddyparkinson yeah I don't mind writing code. I just need to figure out a way to do it and I'll take it from there. Can u post some examples?

Answer (score 0):

The HTML Service is a good way to do this. The tutorial is here https://developers.google.com/apps-script/html_service